# jQuery anchor preventDefault

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery, how do I get the value from a textbox and then load a new page based on the value?

For example, lets say the textbox contains "hello" on page1.php, how do I change the default behavior of an anchor tag to now load the following

page2.php?txt=hello

I have the following so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.mylink").click(function(event){
        alert("link clicked");
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Html**

```
    <input type="text" id="demoQuery" />
    <a id='demoLink' href='javascript:'>Iam a link</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
jQuery('#demoLink').bind('click',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      document.location.href="someUrl.php?text="+ jQuery('#demoQuery').val();     
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) event of the text box, so after the user has finished typing the anchor can be updated using the following jQuery:

```
$("#textBoxId").blur(function() {
    var text = $(this).val();
    var end = text.length == 0 ? "" : "?txt=" + text;
    $("a.mylink").attr("href", "Page2.php" + end);
});
```

And just change the href of the anchor. Then you don't need to handle the anchor `click` yourself. The anchor will just redirect to "Page.php?txt=Hello". And this will ensure that the link is always up to date and will work if the user right clicks and selects open in new window.

Or you could do it the other way around and handle the click of the anchor:

```
$("a.mylink").click(function(e) {
   var text = $("#textBoxId").val();
   document.location.href = $(this).attr("href") + "?txt=" + text;
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

But if the user right clicks, this event will not fire.

Comment: I don't really see a benefit of using `blur` over handling the `click` directly.  Actually, it seems like it's the more inefficient way to handle the situation.  The click happens once per page whereas the blur event could happen multiple times.

Comment: @BBonifield. I agree with you. I had it in my head to use `blur` as it would guarantee that the user had put in some input, which is obviously a flawed ideology. Hence why I added the alternative suggestion (similar to yours), with the variation of using `preventDefault` instead of the blanket `return false;` action in order to allow for any propagation. Plus, blur will work if the user right clicks.

Comment: It is not inefficient, just that it will work even if the user right clicks on the link to open in a new tab for example.

Comment: Can the downvoters please explain their reasoning? UPDATE: Just replaced `.text()` with `.val()` if that was the reason?

Comment: +1 Because you're actually handling both left and right click in your first example.

Comment: For the second version, it't creating the correct url. It makes http://intranet/page1.php?txt=hello

Comment: it should be changing page1 to page2. and then adding the extra string.

Comment: Change the href attribute on your anchor to `href="Page2.php"` then. Or am I misunderstanding you?

Answer (score 3):

Set a click event on the anchor tag to add the query string when it is clicked.

```
$('a').click(function() {
   var querystring = $('input').serialize();
   this.href += querystring;
});
```

This uses jQuery's [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method.  Where the selector is every input or field you want to pass the field to the next page.  Good luck!

No need to use event.preventDefault.

Comment: If you have just one input you can adress that one only and get its value by $('#input').val(). That should be faster if theres only one input..