# Javascript Prevent Default Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault

I know there are many posts about there regarding preventDefault() not working but I went to those and got nothing out of it.

All I'm doing is catching a click event and then appending the html from the response but preventDefault() isn't stopping the page from reloading and I'm confused why.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="slide_pane"> 
 <div class="profile_content"></div>

 <div class="account_bottom_bar">
  <ul class="bottom_bar_list">
    <a href="/profiles/load" class="sidebar_link">
      <li>
        <p>Content</p>
      </li>
    </a>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

And here's my JS:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
 ajaxView();
});

var ajaxView = function() {
 $('.sidebar_link').click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $.ajax ({
  type: 'GET',
  url: $(this).attr("href")

  }).done(function(resp) {
   $('.profile_content').append(resp);
  });
 });
};
```

But when I hit that action, it just loads the HTML from the response in a new screen.

Any ideas?? Thanks!

Comment: Where is the `.sidebar_link` element in your example? It looks like you are adding a new event handler to that element whenever the users scrolls the page, which is really bad.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery anchor preventDefault](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786898/jquery-anchor-preventdefault)

Comment: Sorry Felix Kling. just edited it... it's on the link

Comment: One potential problem could be that your HTML is invalid. Only `li` elements are valid children of an `ul` element. Move the link *inside* the `li` element. But aside from that, your code seems to work, at least in Firfox: http://jsfiddle.net/nAS3S/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing happens because there is no sidebar_link in your HTML.

Example use of event.preventDefault():

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".sidebar_link").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).css("color", "red");
    });   
});
```

Here is an example how to use event.preventDefault() on links: http://jsfiddle.net/LUKVT/

Comment: I am using your code and it does not reload here: http://jsfiddle.net/y4FRr/ Am i missing something?

Comment: So I just noticed I'm using document.scroll instead of .ready :P But what was weird was that when I brought the chrome inspector up and hit that action, it wouldn't reload but when I didn't have the inspector up, it would reload... don't really get that part

Comment: @user3029619: Maybe opening the inspector triggered a scroll event.

Comment: Fair enough - i was suspicious about that onScroll event :))