# Tweet button opening new window and new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I am doing FreeCodeCamp's Random Quote Machine exercise.

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22962821/4956253), I tried to set up my tweet button to open up a new window rather than a tab that the user could use to Tweet this quotes with.

The only issue is is that it is opening up a new tab **as well as** a new window. Is there any way I could get it to just open the new window?

**HTML for Tweet Link**

```
<a class="twitter-share-button" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet" target="_newwin">
Tweet</a>
```

**Related JavaScript**

```
jQuery('a[target^="_newwin"]').click(function() {
    var width = 500;
    var height = 300;
    window.open(this.href , 'newwindow', 'width=' + width + ', height=' + height + ', top=' + ((window.innerHeight - height) / 2) + ', left=' + ((window.innerWidth - width) / 2));
});
```

[Pen of my Project](http://codepen.io/DouglasSymb/pen/QEoVgw)

Thank you!

Comment: At a guess the new window (or tab) is opened because of the default behavior of the anchor, try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786898/jquery-anchor-preventdefault

Comment: An easy workaround is to just add `onclick="return false;"` to your anchor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting both your custom behavior (opening a new window) and the standard behavior of a link (in most browser nowadays, opening a new tab). To prevent the latter, you need to use the ´preventDefault´ method:

```
jQuery('a[target^="_newwin"]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var width = 500;
    var height = 300;
    window.open(this.href , 'newwindow', 'width=' + width + ', height=' + height + ', top=' + ((window.innerHeight - height) / 2) + ', left=' + ((window.innerWidth - width) / 2));
});
```

Comment: That fixed my problem and gave me a greater understanding of what preventDefault() is for, thank you Martin!